# Symfony2 Validation against entire entity

Tags: validation, symfony, entities

I need to be able to do complex custom validation of an entire entity in Symfony2.

Eg: my `entity` has many `subentities`, and all `subentities` must sum to 100.

As far as I can fathom, Symfony2 validators only validate singular fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. You need to specify your constraint against the object rather than a parameter, and specify the constraint that its a class level constraint. A somewhat verbose example is this:

config.yml

```
validator.my.uniquename:
  class: FQCN\To\My\ConstraintValidator
  arguments: [@service_container]
  tags:
    - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: ConstraintValidator }
```

validation.yml

```
FQCN\To\My\Entity:
  constraints:
    - FQCN\To\MyConstraint: ~
```

(no args for the constraint in this example)

My Constraint

```
namespace FQCN\To;

use 
  Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint
  ;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class MyConstraint extends Constraint
{
  public $message = 'Constraint not valid';

  public function validatedBy()
  {
    return 'ConstraintValidator';
  }

  public function getTargets() 
  {
    # This is the important bit.
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
  }
}
```

My ConstraintValidator

```
class MyConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  protected $container;

  function __construct($container)
  {
    $this -> container = $container;
  }

  function isValid($object, Constraint $constraint)
  {
    # validation here.
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any tips to solve `The constraint MyBundle\Validator\Constraint cannot be put on properties or getters` ?

Comment: @greg and for future visitors, you must put the constraint annotation ABOVE the class declaration.

Comment: More precision when writing answers please.

Comment: @PAM, how would you advise for more precision? The example seems quite precise to me.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand something. Finally I figured it out with official docs. I can't give you +1 back until you edit the post  :)

Comment: The key is in Constraint::getTargets() method: by default it uses self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT but to validate the entire entity it is necessary to use self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT constant. Everything else is standard validator.